# What do the "four horns" in Zechariah 1:18-21 refer to?

Tags: word-study, zechariah

Can somebody help me out in finding this answer. If we read prophet Zechariah it mentioned four horns which refers to Judah, Israel, and Jerusalem. But I didn't get this, it was four horns but we see only three which it referred do. So which or what it refers to the another one horn? (1:18-21)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The four horns are our bad habits as of these days that brings our spiritual life down
like Pride,,Adultery. Selfishness,

Pride --thinking you do better than others 
           -Looking down on others
Adultery -  No self control 
              -Sleeping with men or women outside your marriage or before wedding
Selfishness  -- Not thinking of other peoples problems but just of yourself. your kids ,your job,your money

Comment: How do you know this? Please [edit] this to add supporting evidence to support your conclusion.

Answer (score 5):

Zech 1:19 specifically says, "These are the horns which have scattered Judah, Israel and Jerusalem."  The NLT offers a more interpretive translation, "These horns represent the nations that scattered Judah, Israel, and Jerusalem."

Thus, the horns represented the nations that besieged and captured the Israelite community including Judah and Jerusalem.  Historically (before the final deportation of Jews by Nebuchadnezzar) such nations included:

- The Assyrians (capital at Nineveh) who ended the northern Kingdom of Israel about 722 BC
- Syria (often called Aram, capital Damascus) helped destroy the northern kingdom of Israel before it was destroyed itself about 732 BC and became part of Assyria.
- Egypt also attacked Jerusalem and Samaria, beginning with the invasion shortly after Solomon.  King Josiah was killed by Egyptians who also deposed King Jehoahaz and his son made vassal to Egypt.
- Babylon who attacked Jerusalem under Nebuchadnezzar at least 3 times and finally ended the Jewish monarchy about 586 BC.

All these attacked Jerusalem, Judah and Samaria at various times and so became the four horns that "scattered" the Jews.

Comment: If we think and take in that way it make sense. Thank you

Comment: Glad to be of service.

Answer (score 0):

The 4 horns here is referred to as the neighboring nations or powers that are against Israel, Judah and Jerusalem. And this 4 horns can be seen as evil powers or lifestyle or sin or shortcomings etc that is pressing us down so that we will not raise our head

Comment: Welcome to BH Community! Good  focused answer, good application. Aramaic Bible translate as "four kingdoms" which could be four historical empires that conquered and scattered Judah, Israel, and Jerusalem, Assyria, Egypt, Babylonia, and Medo-Persia, and these forces are still at working against the people of God.